# C# - System.IO.IOException

Tags: c#, dialog, ioexception, savefiledialog

I have a method that saves the text from a text box into a txt file but I get an System.IO.IOException error every time I back out of the SaveFileDialog.

```
    static OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    static SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    static String cp;

    private void SaveClass() {
        sfd.DefaultExt = "txt";
        sfd.Filter = "Text Files | *.txt";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            cp = sfd.FileName;
            File.Create(cp);

            File.WriteAllLines(@cp, StudentTextBox.Text.Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

        }
    }
```

Visual Studio highlights the code that starts with "File.WriteAllLines" and says that's where I'm getting the error. Thanks.

Exact error message:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\ktfjulien\Documents\poop.txt' because it is being used by another process.

EDIT:
Thank you, I no longer get the error message but everything I save into the text box is written onto one line, regardless if the text is delimited by new lines or not.

Comment: And error message?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to do `File.Create(cp);` to write to a file. This is the cause of the error. Instead, directly do:

```
cp = sfd.FileName;
FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(cp);
```

And if you want to use the `StreamWriter` instead of `FileStream`, use the `FileStream` as the input for your `StreamWriter`

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
```

Or, you could also directly use `File.WriteAllLines` as you show - don't use the `File.Create`:

```
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    cp = sfd.FileName;
    //File.Create(cp); //remove this

    File.WriteAllLines(@cp, StudentTextBox.Text.Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating file using `File.Create()` this file is already used by `File.Create()` you need close that file before use another place so before writing text to the file close file writer

```
var file = File.Create(cp);
file.Close();
```

complete working solution

```
static OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
static SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
static String cp;
private void SaveClass()
{
    sfd.DefaultExt = "txt";
    sfd.Filter = "Text Files | *.txt";
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        cp = sfd.FileName;
        var file = File.Create(cp);
        file.Close();

        File.WriteAllLines(@cp, StudentTextBox.Text.Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no need to create the file, `File.WriteAllLines` will do it for you (or clear up the file if it exists):

```
  private void SaveClass() {
    sfd.DefaultExt = "txt";
    sfd.Filter = "Text Files | *.txt";

    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
      File.WriteAllLines(sfd.FileName, StudentTextBox.Text
        .Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine },
               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
  }
```